# How can I setup access to a private github repository in Openshift 3?

Tags: github, repository, openshift, credentials

Well, i'm using Openshift to host a node.js application, and some things need to be private. So i need to let Openshift acess my Git repository in private.
I found some tutorials in the internet, but no one helped me.
I tried using PuTTY, i used Git Bash, but i failed everytime.
Everytime i get this error from Openshift:

`error: build error: failed to fetch requested repository "myrepository.git" with provided credentials`

(i changed the repository url in the error)

Well, what can i do to setup Openshift to acess a private repository?
I'm using OpenShift 3.

Comment: If you are using OpenShift 3, what you need are source clone secrets. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-clone-secrets Be careful you aren't looking at older OpenShift 2 documentation. If something mentions ``rhc`` it is for OpenShift 2, not OpenShift 3.

Comment: "Command "new-basicauth" is deprecated, use oc create secret"

Comment: Apart from steps from Jérôme Verstrynge, what worked for me is changing the repo from "Clone with HTTPS, https://github.com/.........." to "Clone with SSH, git@github.com:red.........." as [shown in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4xOt.jpg)

Answer (score 16):

It took me a bit of time to figure it out, since the last step is missing in the [configuration](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-clone-secrets).

In order to give OpenShift 3 access to a private github repository, I performed the following:

```
> oc secrets new-basicauth github-credentials --username=<yourgithubusername> --password=<yourgithubpassword>
```

It returns:

```
secret/github-credentials
```

Then (and here is the missing part) from the Openshift 3 web interface:

1. Click on `Build`
2. Click on your application's link
3. On the top right, click on `Action` and select `Edit`
4. Underneath `Git Repository URL`, click on `Advanced Options`
5. In `Source Secrets`, select `github-credentials`
6. Click on `Save` at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution:
consider that I am using  openshift version 3.11
So, on the left side menu click on "Builds" then "Builds" again, then click on the name of your project, now click on the action button and select "edit" option. now click on "Show advanced options", in the Build Secret Section "Create New Secret", put a new secret name and the user name and password that you use for the private repository. Now select a build secret that you have created. That is all!